# Notification email scheduling using node js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, email

I have a notification system for my website. I need a email notification system for website users.

I have email notification setting page from where user can schedule their email on **daily bases or monthly basic or immediate basis or on particular date**.

What is the best approach i need to use for this kind of functionality?

PS: i don't want to use socket.io

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the following:

- In case the email should be sent everytime the event occurs, then you
  don't need any crontab. Just send the email when the event occur.
- Run a crontab once an hour. This crontab will fetch all events from
  the last hour, and send an email with all these events to the users
  requesting a hourly email
- Do the same once a day and once a week for users with daily and
  weekly emails preferences

.